# Force a session to time out every 6h hours

Tags: architecture, tomcat

A marketing guy came to me with a request to time out the session every 6 hours regardless of the user activity on the site.

I understand that if the user leaves his computer for a certain period of time (Set right now to 30 minutes) the session should time out, but forcing a user to log in after a certain period of time just doesn't make sense to me

His reason is that if a person is logged in for 6h on the site, it is most likely a bot.

Is this a valid request ?

-ken

Comment: tell him to stick to marketing in the future

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a very arbitrary and ineffective way to decide when to kill sessions.  The only effective way for spotting a bot that I can think of is tracking the path of  each session to identify whether the activity is suspicious, but even this would be a waste of time.  I would say that is in an invalid request, or at the very least an invalid approach.

OWASP is becoming the industry standard on security.  Here is the session management link for further advice: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to my opinion is what facebook.com do if you seems suspicious to application. It would show you a page with some people and ask you to say which are your friends in a short period of time.
The lesson is to use some business (your website activity) related control for finding out the bot. Logical solutions are always better than simply technical solutions. That's why I didn't advise for something like using CAPTCHA, generating random Id and name for HTML elements everytime a page is generated and ...

Answer (score 0):

To close the session regardless the user activity, use a [SessionListener](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets4.html) and record a timestamp when the session is created as a session attribute.

Then use a (Request) [Filter](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets8.html) to check that the current time is less than 6 hours plus the initial recorded timestamp. If not, `session.invalidate()`.

To force reloading the page after 21600 seconds (don't use this alone, always close the session in the server if you're going to do this, since this runs in the client browser):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="21600">
```

> Is this a valid request ?

Of course, marketing guys *always* issue valid requests.

Regards.